# Getting pointer to C array pointer: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

Usually I feel like I understand the initialization from incompatible pointer type error, but I'm a bit confused here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[10];
    int *p = a;   // fine
    int *q = &a;  // incompatible, expected
    int **z = &a; //incompatible, unexpected

    return 0;
}
```

I assumed that the variable a is interpreted as an `int*` pointer to the first element of `a`, `a[0]`. So I expected `int* q = &a` to give me an incompatible warning, but I thought `int** z = &a` would be correct...?

How is one supposed to actually do this?

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473864/pointer-to-array-in-c The accepted answer has a very similar example.

Comment: It did, sorry. I had seen that one before, but didn't read it carefully enough.