# the meaning of '&' in C when using with array

Tags: c, gcc

I am learning pointer right now, and '&' operator is messing my mind in terms of datatype, especially when it's used with array.

I see that '&' operator is giving me the first memory address of whatever it is used with.

But I can't understand why this is changing the datatype when I use it with array's name. Is this just the way it is? Or are there any reasons that I don't know yet?

so, my question is,

1. why do the datatype of array1 and array 2 is different even though they are just the name of array?
2. why does the datatype changes just because I added '&'?

```
int array1[5];

int *p1 = array1;    //why does this works
int *p2 = &array1;   //but not this one?
```

the gcc says that one on the top right is 'int*' but one with '&' is 'int(*)[5]'.

```
int array2[5][5];

int (*q1)[5] = array2;    //why does this wokrs
int (*q2)[5] = &array2;   //but not this one?
```

the gcc says that one on the top right is 'int( * )[5]' but one with '&' is 'int( * )[5][5]'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I treat an array like a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676402/why-cant-i-treat-an-array-like-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: The unary `&` operator gives the address of its operand.  The data type of the result is pointer to whatever type that operand has.  So if you have `int a`, then `&a` has type `int *`.  If you have `int b[10]` then `&b` has type `int (*)[10]`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/2094795/1524450

Comment: Actually once you're creating an array, the first member of this array  becomes a pointer which points to the ```array1```in your example ```int array1[5];```. So if you do this ```int *p2 = &array1;```you will be taking an address of a pointer since ```array1```is actually a pointer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, array name gets converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.
So you do not need to use '&' to get the address.
When you do this, what you are getting is a pointer to an array.

See also [Pointer to Array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473864/pointer-to-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers in c have very deep implementation. Pointers , as name suggest pointes to a data location. Pointers in c have a datatype which tells about the data type of data.

```
int * ptr;
```

this is pointer daclaration.

int i = 30;
ptr = &i ; // this returns address of variable t

in terms of array
both arr, &arr return address of array

int (*p)[5] = &arr or arr , both works , otherwise send the error message with question.