# What do these declarations mean in C?

Tags: c

The declarations

```
int arr[10];
int *arr1[10];
```

are straightforward. The first declares an array of 10 integers while the second declares a 10 value array of pointers to int (`int *`).

Now, consider these declarations:

```
int (*arr2)[10];
int *(*arr3)[10];
```

What do these even mean? Considering the parenthesis, they are trying to dereference `arr2` and `arr3` in the declaration? Is this even possible?

Can anyone answer what is the type of values stored in these arrays and if I do something like `*arr2` or `*arr3`, what would the value be?

Also, what is the type of `arr2` and `arr3` now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41473864/12416453

Comment: [arr2 as pointer to array 10 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*arr2%29%5B10%5D).

Comment: "what is the type of values stored in these arrays and if I do something like *arr2" --> `arr2` is **not** an array.  It is a pointer.  `arr1` is an _array_.

Answer (score 3):

In these declarations:

```
int arr[10];
int *arr1[10];
int (*arr2)[10];
int *(*arr3)[10];
```

`arr` is an array[10] of `int`s.

`arr1` is an array[10] of pointers to `int`.

`arr2` is a pointer to an array[10] of `int`s.

`arr3` is a pointer to an array[10] of pointers to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

When reading declarations in C where the name is enclosed in parentheses, what helps me is to start at there (hopefully when there is only one name inside it) and, when there is nothing to the right, go left, until you reach a parenthesis, then you go right from the whole parentheses until you reach a parenthesis or the end etc.

So `int (*arr2)[10]` would be (left) a pointer (`*`) to (right) an array (`[10]`) of (left) `int`. `int *(*arr3)[10];` would be a pointer (`*`) to an array (`[10]`) of (left) pointer (`*`) to `int`.

Comment: Mmh, it's the "right-left" rule, not "left-right". In your example you start from arr2, you try to move right, but there's a parenthesis, so you move left and you find the star. So arr2 is a pointer to something. Then, the content of the parentheses is over, so you go again to the right, and continue like that. Otherwise the rule won't work for `int *arr1[10];`

Comment: Yeah, that works better with generalized names that are not enclosed in parentheses